# Merge duplicate objects in array and sum the values

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have an array of objects

```
    [
      {
        "team": "team-a",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-b",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-a",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-b",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-unassigned",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      }
    ]
```

I'm looking for a way to merge objects with duplicate `team` keys and then sum each value in the results object. The final result would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "team": "team-a",
    "results": {
      "passed": 2,
      "failed": 2,
      "flaky": 2,
      "skipped": 2,
      "timedOut": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-b",
    "results": {
      "passed": 2,
      "failed": 2,
      "flaky": 2,
      "skipped": 2,
      "timedOut": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-unassigned",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  }
]
```

I've tried reducing but just can't get to the working solution. Could anyone give some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Have in mind that it modifies `source` array.

```js
const source = [{
    "team": "team-a",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-b",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-a",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-b",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-unassigned",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  }
]
const additional = [{
    "team": "team-a",
    "results": {
      "passed": 2,
      "failed": 2,
      "flaky": 2,
      "skipped": 2,
      "timedOut": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-b",
    "results": {
      "passed": 2,
      "failed": 2,
      "flaky": 2,
      "skipped": 2,
      "timedOut": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "team": "team-unassigned",
    "results": {
      "passed": 1,
      "failed": 1,
      "flaky": 1,
      "skipped": 1,
      "timedOut": 1
    }
  }
]

source.forEach(({
  team,
  results
}) => {
  const {
    results: additionalResults
  } = additional.find(o => o.team === team)
  Object.entries(additionalResults).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    results[key] += value
  })
})

console.log(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes reduce and inside of it you group by item.team into the accumulative variable  having summing all the numbers in results object.

```js
var arr=[{team:"team-a",results:{passed:1,failed:1,flaky:1,skipped:1,timedOut:1}},{team:"team-b",results:{passed:1,failed:1,flaky:1,skipped:1,timedOut:1}},{team:"team-a",results:{passed:1,failed:1,flaky:1,skipped:1,timedOut:1}},{team:"team-b",results:{passed:1,failed:1,flaky:1,skipped:1,timedOut:1}},{team:"team-unassigned",results:{passed:1,failed:1,flaky:1,skipped:1,timedOut:1}}]

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.team] = agg[item.team] || {
    team: item.team,
    results: {}
  };
  for (var key in item.results) {
    agg[item.team].results[key] = (agg[item.team].results[key] || 0) + item.results[key]
  }
  return agg;
}, {}))

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let input = [
      {
        "team": "team-a",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-b",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-a",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-b",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      },
      {
        "team": "team-unassigned",
        "results": {
          "passed": 1,
          "failed": 1,
          "flaky": 1,
          "skipped": 1,
          "timedOut": 1
        }
      }
    ];

let resultObj = {};
input.forEach((entry) => {
    let resultTypes = Object.keys(entry.results);
    resultTypes.map((type) => {
        resultObj[entry.team] = resultObj[entry.team] || {
            "team" : entry.team,
            "results" : {}
        };
        resultObj[entry.team].results[type] =  (resultObj[entry.team].results[type] || 0) + entry.results[type];  
    });
});
console.log( Object.values(resultObj) );
```